# Manage import correctly in Python

Tags: python, import, directory, parent

My question may be a duplicate but I really don't know why it does not work well.
In my project, I have lots of unitary test. To correspond to our api, tests are written like that

```
mother
--> test_mother
   child1
   --> test_child1
      child2
      --> test_child2
```

When I go in each directory to launch test individualy, it works fine. But I'd like to launch all tests one after another from the mother directory. And I get always an error of bad import.

in test_child1, I do this

```
sys.path.append("../")
from test_mother import Data as data
```

I got this: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_mother'`

and in child2

```
sys.path.append("../../")
from child1.test_child1 import Data as data
```

I had this: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'child1'`

Even after adding `__init__.py` in directories, I got those errors.

Could you explain me what's wrong and how to solve that?

Comment: adding an `__init__.py` file in each of the subfolders will allow you to use the dot notation to import files

Comment: He meant `__init__.py`, but it was working as bold

Comment: I've already added a __init__.py but I used it very badly. After lots of try, I finally find the solution.  I delete sys.path.append("../../") and just use from mother.test_mother  import... or from mother.child1.test_child1 import .... Just after writing the question, I add the solution :). Thanks